# Small Issue - Foursquare Venue API - cURL and json

Tags: php, json, curl, foursquare

I am trying to get the details of a venue in Foursquare using the venue ID, but there is something minor that isn't correct:

```
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'https://api.foursquare.com/v2/venues/4c599c84f346c9287ff84cca?client_id=[MY_ID]&client_secret=[MY_SECRET]&v=20120609');

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
$contents = curl_exec ($ch);
$result = json_decode($contents);
var_dump($result);
curl_close ($ch);
```

- If I change the URL to something like Google News RSS, or one of my XML feed pages, I get results, to the cURL portion is right
- If I paste the above URL into my browser (with my actual ID&Secret) then I get a json formatted result with the data that I expect (correct name of venue, etc). So I know the URL is correct.
- If I copy the json from the above process and put it into a variable in my code, then set $result to the decode version of that variable then I see the results properly. So I know that the decode/output bit is working.

Somewhere between retrieving the result and storing it in a variable for decoding something is going wrong. I have to assume it is something silly and simple, since all of the parts are there, but I can't figure it out.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Your data is disappearing between the time you get it into $contents and you decode it to $results? Probably invalid json... did you check json_last_error()

Comment: This is my first cURL or json foray so I didn't know that existed. Thanks for the tip. I have checked it now and it comes back as 0, but in the documentation it looks like there should at lease be "JSON_ERROR_NONE" if there is no error. Maybe I am not getting results.

That is weird because I can get results with different urls and if I just use that URL by itself (in the browser) it returns a result.

Comment: Ok, I re-read that and implemented it using the switch statement from the documentation and it comes back as "No Errors"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer turned out to be that I had to add the following 2 lines:

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 0);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0);
```